# Where is the airport in Disneyland Paris? (DLP)

Tags: airport, france

I just found out that there is an airport in Disneyland Paris with the IATA code DLP. Since I've never heard of it, I wanted to see it on Google Maps, but haven't found it.

Is there actually an airport, and where?

Why does Disneyland has its own, with CDG not far away?

Comment: Where did you find it? Is it really official? It does not seem to be listed in official-looking lists.

Comment: @JanHudec Actually I've found it in our database, as far as I know imported from some IATA file (obviously containing also non-airport entries, like I've found XED too).
One reference in the web I've found: http://www.flightstats.com/go/Airport/airportDetails.do?airportCode=DLP

Comment: I confirm, the nearest airport is CDG. You can then take a bus (called optile) and be there in about one hour, making an extra airport useless. But there is no IATA code [DLP](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/code-search.aspx).

Comment: Is it possibly a heliport?

Comment: @ManuH Or the TGV, 15 minutes

Comment: I recall being told that disneyland has an IATA code so that your bags can be checked all the way to your resort hotel and you don't have to pick them up at the airport when you land.

Comment: This seems more about travel than aviation to me, although I can see why it might seem like an aviation question

Answer (score 15):

IATA codes don't necessarily correspond to airports. Some non-airports have IATA codes to allow airlines to sell through tickets that might, for example, consist of travelling from A to B by plane and then onward from B to C by train. DLP isn't on [Wikipedia's list of railway stations with IATA codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IATA-indexed_railway_stations) but I imagine something very similar is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wasn't aware of it! I've found XED, which seems to be the railway station in Disneyland Paris.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there actually an airport, and where?

Disneyland does not have an airport in Paris,France.

Disneyland, Paris is situated approximately 20 miles from Paris.

There is a direct Shuttle Bus Airport Transfer to Disneyland from

(a) Charles de Gaulle,
(b) Orly and 
(c) Beauvais airport.

http://vea-shuttle.co.uk/

> I wanted to see it on Google Maps, but haven't found it.

Please check the Google Map here

http://www.airportia.com/france/disneyland-paris-airport/map/

Comment: `Paris,France` _in case you confused it with Paris Hilton_ [ [cit](http://youtu.be/U6oTwirTCeY?t=15m33s) ]

Comment: @Federico: Or the wonderful [Paris, Texas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087884/).

Comment: @mins how dare you leave out [Paris, ID](https://goo.gl/maps/FieHvY6eoYi7GwHY8)!

Comment: @FreeMan: This one is  [well known in France](https://www.maathiildee.com/bienvenue-a-paris-dans-lidaho/), we know everything about it and the 504 souls who live there.

Comment: @mins that's fantastic!! Paris, ID is about a 2 hour drive from where I grew up. It's existence (along with Moscow, ID) helped impress my (then) college girlfriend (now wife)! She though I was quite the world traveler... It was a couple of years before I clarified _her_ misunderstanding of "Paris" and "Moscow". ;)

Comment: @ah! I love these names. There is a story about [Syracuse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZNnJvVJNmU) sung by a french singer in NY (in the 60s or 70s). But nobody could understand why he wanted to see [Syracuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syracuse,_New_York) then Easter Island before dying...

Answer (score 0):

closet airport for disneyland paris is cdg charles de gaulle. 
also orly airport  cdg is most convient airport for dinsyeland paris

beauvais airport 130 km  fromdisneyland  ( special for rayan air )

[private transfers from cdg to disneyland paris](http://www.privatetransfercdgdisneyland.com/)

[Nearest Airport to Disneyland Paris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcbiyIg5oik)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for helicopters? Looking at google maps there seem to be helipads on one of the parking lots - https://goo.gl/maps/Z2BKE6aH7vF5tyCT9